# Implementations of Oauth service provider for Java or Php

Tags: google-app-engine, cakephp, oauth

I would like to implement OAuth as a service provider for my website (Google App engine Java, and also CakePhp) but I could not find any good library/tutorial.
Does anybody have good references?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to implement the OAuth provider within you application. You can use things like http://github.com/mohangk/appengine_oauth_provider to help you implement this.

Answer (score 3):

This might actually be a more helpful guide to what you want to do, since it is specifically about building a OAuth Provider in PHP:

http://toys.lerdorf.com/archives/55-Writing-an-OAuth-Provider-Service.html